# Can't open include file in microC

Tags: microcontroller, keil, microc

I m trying write a little program for a microcontroller using microC, and I m getting this message[image: Screenshot from my microC]

Since I m just a beginner I m confused about what is causing this problem, 
in my program I have one include line #include, I commented the same error remains, and its the only include in that program. any help?

Comment: Couldn't begin to tell you without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings for compiler include paths. The path to that file needs to be in there, otherwise the compiler cannot find your #include file, and you get that error.

Comment: Can u give me a step by step explanation sir?

Comment: On Keil uVision: Project -> Options for Target 'your target' -> C/C++ -tab -> Include Paths. Add the path to your file there.